# SSRS export to excel on separate worksheets issue

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm using SSRS 2008 to export data to an excel file. I need 4 worksheets in the file. As a result, I'm inserting a page break after each Tablix. But when there's no data in the page,it's merging the sheet with the next one. I looked up for help, I found one where it says I need to insert a rectangle to avoid this. I'm not sure how I do this. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To add a rectangle On the Insert tab, in the Report Items group, click
>   Rectangle. On the design surface, click the location where you want
>   the upper left corner of the rectangle, and drag to where you want the
>   lower-right corner. Note that as you move the cursor, "snap lines"
>   appear as the cursor lines up with other objects on the design
>   surface. These help you if you want objects to be aligned.

Then I believe you set the page break to occur after the rectangle instead of after the tablix